# Sentiment classifcation - Publicly available datasets for market/trading/financial news sentiment

Tags: classification, sentiment-analysis, finance

As the title suggest, I'm looking for publicly available datasets to train a classifier to distinguish bullish from non-bullish or bearish from non-bearish news.

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch, I think this is a fair comment. I flagged the question.